# Android: Remotevideo displaying blank screen on firefox and opera using Sinch video sdk

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am using [Sinch](http://sinch.com) for video calling between android app and web browser.In chrome its working perfectly.Both localvideo and remotevideo views are visible.But in Firefox it gives mediaStreamError and in opera the remote video view in both android and web browser is blank(black).
Firefox error :

```
15:26:14.585 Error retrieving media stream MediaStreamError { name: "NotReadableError", message: "Failed to allocate videosource", constraint: "", stack: "" } 1 sinch.min.js:5:14794
```

opera blank screen screenshot :

[image]

what could be the problem?